# retrieving data in PHP by C# HttpWebRequest using PUT --- C# -> PHP using Slim Rest Framework

Tags: c#, php, put, slim

I´m new to Slim and I´ve some issues retrieving data sending stuff via a httpwebrequest using "PUT". I know http is not rest! ;) and i know the data is send correctly. so, what am i missing? yes, i could send all the data via the headers, but i don´t want to use such a work around.

so this is what i do:

C#:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
request.KeepAlive = true;

// Set request method
request.Method = method.ToUpper(); // in this case: "PUT"


var dataByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test=test"); // <-- DATA to be send
request.ContentLength = dataByte.Length;

using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    dataStream.Write(dataByte, 0, dataByte.Length);
}


var res = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var resStream = res.GetResponseStream();
if (resStream != null)
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
    responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
}
if (resStream != null) resStream.Close();
res.Close();
```

PHP: using Slim and "PUT"

```
$app->put('/someendpoint', function ($somevar) {
   // THIS IST THE PLACE WHERE I NEED THE DATA : "test"
});
```

works perfectly when using POST or GET (of course), like

```
if(isset($_POST['test']))
echo $_POST['test'];
```

but i need something like

```
$_PUT['test']
```

...soooo how could i do that? 
i´m sure there´s a solution and i think may people out there have issues on that.

thx in advance for helping me out! :)

Answer (score 0):

...found it:
i did some research and read this tutorial again (...and again...and again...) ;)

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/

all i had to do is using this neat function to get the body information to parse the stuff:

```
function verifyRequiredParams($required_fields) {
    $error = false;
    $error_fields = "";
    $request_params = array();
    $request_params = $_REQUEST;
    // Handling PUT request params
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        parse_str($app->request()->getBody(), $request_params);
    }
    foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
        if (!isset($request_params[$field]) || strlen(trim($request_params[$field])) <= 0) {
            $error = true;
            $error_fields .= $field . ', ';
        }
    }

    if ($error) {
        // Required field(s) are missing or empty
        // echo error json and stop the app
        $response = array();
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = 'Required field(s) ' . substr($error_fields, 0, -2) . ' is missing or empty';
        echoRespnse(400, $response);
        $app->stop();
    }
}
```

and i had to change my api call to:

```
$app->put('/someendpoint', function ($somevar) use($app){

    verifyRequiredParams(array('test'));
    $test= $app->request->put('test');
    echo $test;
});
```